# How do I get an actual string into a char variable string (char variable with brackets) in Arduino?

Tags: string, arduino, char, arduino-esp8266

I have the problem with a NodeMCU with an ESP8266 and the ArduinoIDE:

I want the to use a softAP and the password for this is supposed to be generated randomly everytime the devices is starting, it is supposed to be 8 digits long, just enough to be displayed on my 8digit 7segment display.
I created a number that is being 8digits long and being converted to a String directly. Sadly, the "WiFi.softAP" command only accepts the variable type constant character, in brackets. How can I somehow get the string into a char with brackets or get WiFi.softAP to swallow a String type?

I am already this far:

```
MAX7219_7segment PWScreen(14,12,13);
String A,B,C;
const char *ssid = "Sellerie";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

/* Just a little test message.  Go to http://192.168.4.1 in a web browser
 * connected to this access point to see it.
 */
void handleRoot() {
    server.send(200, "text/plain", C);
}

void setup() {
  int pw = random(10000000,99999999);
  String spassword = String(pw);
  //const char *password = spassword;
  pinMode(0, INPUT);  // D0
  pinMode(5, INPUT);  //D1 
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Configuring access point...");
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, spassword);
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
  PWScreen.write_number(pw);
```

Best regards
Sellerie

Comment: `const char *password = spassword.c_str();`

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CStr

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I simply uncommented the integer to string line

`//const char *password = spassword;`

and made `const char *password = spassword;` to `const char *password = spassword.c_str();` as Bence Kaulics answered in the comment under my post, which works flawlessly.
Thanks!